# PHP get_class_methods() returning null when methods exist

Tags: php

I have a class I'm using with three methods, the constructor and two others.  When I run `get_class_methods(new classForTesting())` or `get_class_methods('classForTesting')` it returns null, even though there are three methods in the class. I've spent more time Googling this problem than I'd care to admit, to no avail.

Why is `get_class_methods()` not working for me?  Have I set up my class improperly or is it something else?

**EDIT:**  This is part of a codebase I'm working with at a company, and I'm not sure how much I'm allowed to post publicly.  What I've posted below is a pared down version of what I'm working with.  The code is basically the same, but the first class is much longer and has more functions.

My code:

```
class someOtherClass {
    private $aVar;

    public function someFunction() {
        return "data";
    }
}

class classForTesting {
    public $testVar;

    public function classForTesting () {
        return true;
    }

    public function methodTrue () {
        return true;
    }

    public function methodFalse () {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your class actually loaded? If I paste your code exactly as written and call `var_dump(get_class_methods('classForTesting'));` I get the three methods returned.

Comment: Works fine for me with your class. If you're loading the class with `require` or `include`, have you executed that statement before calling `get_class_methods`?

Comment: [Works for me](http://3v4l.org/fTVcL)

Comment: The class isn't being loaded from an external resource, It's in the file so `include` or `require` shouldn't be causing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your return of this code:

```
<?php
class classForTesting {
    public $testVar;

    public function classForTesting () {
        return true;
    }

    public function methodTrue () {
        return true;
    }

    public function methodFalse () {
        return false;
    }
}
print_r(get_class_methods('classForTesting'));
```

when you save it to **test.php** and run:

> php test.php

you should get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => classForTesting
    [1] => methodTrue
    [2] => methodFalse
)
```

what is your response?

Comment: The code works in a standalone file, but when I add the `print_r()` statement to the file I'm working in it doesn't return anything.  The code I posted is pared down from what I'm working with because I'm unsure what I'm allowed to post publicly (This is part of a codebase for work).  The short explanation is that I've got another class in the file which I figured was causing the problem, but when I add a class to `test.php` that you provided, it still prints the appropriate data.

Comment: Try to add a test method to your class:
`public function testMethod() {
     die("reached this code!");
 }`
and then instantiate your class:
`$test = new classForTesting();`
and call the method:
`$test->testMethod();`
as I think you possibly include/require the class wrong.

Comment: The code is in the same file it's being called from, but I put in your `testMethod` and it does die appropriately.

Comment: Do you use any MVC framework or catch output using ob_ methods?

Comment: I ran the code through an `ob_` statement, and it returned the methods correctly.  Apparently it's not cooperating with one of the functions already in the codebase.  I'm gonna mark your answer as correct seeing as how you helped me get to that conclusion.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/

It works  - you just have to print_r the results. Try it yourself:

```
class classForTesting {
    public $testVar;

    public function classForTesting() {
        return true;
    }

    public function methodTrue() {
        return true;
    }

    public function methodFalse() {
        return false;
    }
}
print_r( get_class_methods('classForTesting') );
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to:

1. enable error reporting (error_reporting(E_ALL)) and set display_errors to 1 with ini_set
2. use: while (@ob_end_flush());
3. where do you print output? is this class has been loaded? are you using __autoload? try to manually require this class.
4. Print something before and after your var_dump to make sure you are not in some try/catch/ob/other.  Maybe this null is not your null.
5. var_dump(class_exists('classForTesting'))
6. use phpinfo to check if this code uses RunKit to modify classes on runtime.
7. use Reflection: $r = new ReflectionClass('classForTesting'); $r->getMethods(); use reflection to get file name an check if this is the same file.
8. use xdebug to manually check what is going on